# Highlight the Validation Error on the corresponding Field

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, lightning-events, lightninginput, lightning-inputfield

Can anyone tell how the implementation of highlighting the validation error at field level can be achieved using Lightning Aura Components?

I have tried using validity functionality option in my code but that is not working

Comment: what have you tried so far? where did you get stuck? Can you please highlight in your question?

Comment: Yeah I have mentioned now